# Changing site content in Drupal from UK to US English via database?

Tags: drupal, localization, drupal-8

My company is launching a US website that will initially be a copy of the UK version. CMS is Drupal 8.

The UK site has approximately 120 pages + plenty of content in custom blocks. We would like to automate the easy changes (spelling and terminology)

My thought is to generate a master list of UK words that should be replaced by American versions (colour, aluminium, organise etc.) and run a simple find and replace in the database.

It should fix: all standard text content, URL aliases, page names etc.

Anyone tried this? Is it plausible?

*FYI: I'm not a developer, but do the content management*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, not a bad idea. I'm doing that i.e. when client uses absolute paths inside content and they want to change domain, add SSL or something. It's totally doable, only problem is that Drupal's database can be very large sometime and can be challenging to find proper tool to do search/replace.

Make a backup and go for it (carefully).